# How do you use :as and match a route correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is my route:

```
resources :stores do 
   get '/add_shoes' => 'stores#add_shoes', :as => :add_shoes
end
```

And my path should be: `<%= link_to "Add Shoes", add_shoes_path %>`

But it gives the error that the path does not exist. How do I use both of them?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can use `rake routes` (you may need to do `bundle exec rake routes` depending on your setup) to see a list of all the routes your app knows about. You should be able to find it in the list.

Comment: Is there a difference in doing it in the resources as having a separate line starting with match instead of get?

Comment: @Emily I did take a look at the routes and got back: `store_add_shoes GET    /stores/:store_id/add_shoes(.`. strange route to me.....When I want to just be `/add_shoes`.

Comment: @kobaltz I don't really understand what you mean. You mean if I change it to use `match` instead of `get`? It still will give the same `NameError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, because it's nested in a `resources` block, it's going to append `stores` to the end.  So the correct route is add_shoes_stores_path.  Sometimes it also adds an index to the end (not sure why), to give you add_shoes_stores_index_path.

Since it's a `get` call, you could always put it outside the `resources` block.

Additionally, the more Rails way to do it would be:

```
resources :stores do
  collection do
    get :add_shoes
  end
end
```

You've got a bunch of options here on how you want to handle it.  But just a quick tip, you can always type `rake routes` from the command line to get a list of all available routes and where they point.

If you're looking at doing it this way for your clarity of code, just remember this: Your routes should always mention where they're pointing to.  That would be both `add_shoes` and `stores`.  Having an `add_shoes_path` could point to literally any controller, as it's not really verbose.  I would definitely stick to the Rails way of doing it - it will make more sense as you dive in deeper.

Finally, another thought - If you're adding shoes in the stores model, it would make sense for each store to have shoes.  You should probably create a new model for Shoes and use RESTFUL routing.